# Ubuntu LTS 18.04 cannot connect VGA monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, 18.04

Recently upgraded laptop to 18.04 64 bit having previously used 32 bit version.

When I plug in a VGA monitor the laptop screen goes black and nothing appears on the external monitor. It worked fine previously on the 32 bit set-up.

Typing xrandr in a terminal with the monitor plugged in yields the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1280x800      59.98*+  59.97    59.81    59.91
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
   960x600       59.93    60.00
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   576x432       60.06
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32

VGA-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     59.93 +
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1280x960      60.00
   1280x800      59.81
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   640x480       59.94
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Cormac

Comment: Still haven't solved this one. I briefly got the VGA monitor to work by typing xrandr --output VGA-1 --right-of LVDS-1. However, that hasn't worked since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got monitors to work finally. Opened a terminal and plugged in second monitor. While both screens were blank, typed the following:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --auto --right-of LVDS-1
```

Hit enter and both monitors worked.